# How to generate new .pot file from a child theme footer.php file ?

Tags: php, wordpress, translate

How should I write the text elements in my new footer.php file for my child theme so that I can extract the strings and translate it into Spanish? Please note, I do not have experience in .php.

Below is the section within the child theme footer.php file that I want to translate:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="fw-col-xs-12 fw-col-sm-15">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="fw-col-inner" style="padding: 0 15px;">
        <h6 style="text-align: left; text-transform:uppercase; color:#ffffff; padding-bottom:5px;">Our Mission</h6>
         <div class="footer-special-text">Barcelona Well Woman’s mission is to empower our clients to live a healthy and balanced life through personalized, natural and holistic treatments--resulting in a more joyous life.</div>
        </div>
         </div>
          </div>

         <div class="fw-col-xs-12 fw-col-sm-15">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="fw-col-inner" style="padding: 0 15px;">
        <h6 style="text-align: left; text-transform:uppercase; color:#ffffff; padding-bottom:5px;">Our Location</h6>
        <div class="services-list">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/contact-page/"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#FFBF5F;"></i> &nbsp; Barcelona, Spain Calle Casp 80, 1-3</a></div></li></ul>
        </div>
         </div>
          </div>

          <div class="fw-col-xs-12 fw-col-sm-15">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="fw-col-inner" style="padding: 0 15px;">
        <h6 style="text-align: left; text-transform:uppercase; color:#ffffff; padding-bottom:5px;">Contact Us</h6>
         <div class="services-list">
         <ul class="footer-content">
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/contact-page/"><i class="fa fa-phone" style="color:#FFBF5F;"></i> &nbsp; 622 720 499</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:info@bcnwellwoman.com"><i class="fa fa fa-envelope" style="color:#FFBF5F;"></i> &nbsp; info@bcnwellwoman.com</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/bcnwellwoman"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:#FFBF5F;"></i> &nbsp; Like our page on Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
          </div>

           <div class="fw-col-xs-12 fw-col-sm-15">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="fw-col-inner" style="padding: 0 15px;">
        <h6 style="text-align: left; text-transform:uppercase; color:#ffffff; padding-bottom:5px;">Our Services & Therapies</h6>
         <div class="services-list">
         <ul>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/acupuncture/">Acupuncture</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/massage/">Massage</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/natural-fertility/">Natural Fertility</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/nutrition-naturopathy/">Nutrition & Naturopathy</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/osteopathy/">Osteopathy</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/physiotherapy/">Physiotherapy</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/psychology-psychotherapy/">Psychology & Psychotherapy</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/pilates/">Pilates</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/yoga/">Yoga</a></li>


        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
          </div>


               <div class="fw-col-xs-12 fw-col-sm-15">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="fw-col-inner" style="padding: 0 15px;">
        <h6 style="text-align: left; text-transform:uppercase; color:#ffffff; padding-bottom:5px;">Language</h6>
         <div class="services-list">
         <ul>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/es/inicio/">Español</a></li>


        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
          </div>



           </div>
           </div>



  <?php
```

/**ends custom footer*/

Comment: This is not quite enough information.  Does the rest of the theme translate? If so, we need to know the language textdomain.  Look (in your functions file) for something like `__(` (two underscores) and copy that whole line back into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding cale_b ! I was indeed able to translate the custom footer texts by adding the following code to each list item I needed to translate: , but I am frustrated because I have been unable to get the links to switch for the language.

For example, On the Spanish version of the website /es/ when I click on the footer link "Acupuntura" I am taken to the English version of the page. (because that is what is hard coded into the footer ?) I am not sure how to get the links to change to the page in Spanish ? 
Below is a snippet of the footer.php code:

`<div class="services-list">
             <ul> 
            <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/acupuncture/"><?php _e("Acupuncture", "wellnesscenter-child"); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://test.bcnwellwoman.com/en/services/massage/"><?php _e("Massage", "wellnesscenter-child"); ?></a></li>`